# Possible to aggregate broadband for a bonded upload?

Tags: networking, bonding

I am looking for a way to aggregate multiple aDSL lines and a cable Internet line to produce a network capable of providing greater speeds in terms of download and upload. I have a video conferencing system that will be installed that requires 2 Mbps upload for a point-to-point connection but the ISPs only provide a maximum of 1 Mbps.

My main concern is if one connection will could use the multiple connections to connect to another point using the combined upload speed.

I looked into 802.3ad but it doesn't look like it bonds the uploads like I would like it to. Another company I looked at was Mushroom Networks where they have products to bond connections together but requires that their product install one both ends or one on one end and the other at an intermediate location (like a data centre).

Is there another method or product that would be able to bond the connections to provide the upload speed I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be out of luck I'm sorry, although there are ways of aggregating multiple links it almost always requires both ends to be configured similarly (for instance .ad, which is an ethernet protocol extension, and you're using DSL not ethernet) - and your ISPs won't do this. One thing that is easy is to setup a router to receive and send traffic down different links based on a number of factors - this is usually in the form of static or policy-based routing.

Sorry to have not provided you with the answer you're looking for.

Comment: That is actually the answer I was expecting. Thanks for such a quick reply. I found some ISPs providing MLPPP and all I'll need to do is get a router that will support it. Although MLPPP doesn't provide much redundancy, it will bond the upload speeds I am looking for. The only thing I need now is, a router to support five links.

Comment: I think you're looking at a decent-sized Cisco or equivilant - give them a call, I have no knowledge of their DSL kit as I don't use it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....I once interviewed with a startup called Mushroom Networks that was trying to do what you want to do.  They did have a device that did the aggregation your suggest.  You might want to examine their website and see what they currently provide: mushroomnetworks.com.

Comment: I suppose you didn't finish reading the post. I have contacted Mushroom Networks but their products require that you have their products on both ends to properly aggregate the upload speed. They offer a service called Broadband Bonding Service, but it is something we didn't want to do.

Comment: Sorry that my suggestion did not meet your needs.  When I very briefly talked to them I thought that they did not have this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A great router for mlppp May be found in the dd_wrt website, cheap routers such as the linksys 54 g can be flashed easily with ddwrt firmware and thus converted and compaired to a 600 dollar router with wireless, mlppp support, load balancing, and 4 WAN ports with 1 remaining for LAN. Mabye 5 WAN and WLAN if you want... If you are lucky enough to have an isp with mlppp than best luck to ya. And Dont let the ddwrt flash process intimadate you, its very easy, and the forums and help files are the most instructive and complete you will ever find anywhere for anything on earth.

Comment: Yeah, we general try to avoid SOHO gear and hacky solutions... this suggestion is both those things.